# Is it possible to combine callbacks and events in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, child-process

I want to run a MongoDB database as a child_process, because some database operations take a lot of time and I don't want the rest of the application to freeze.

I am able to put the database code into a module that reacts and resonds via the event emitter in child_process.

Below is the code in a simplified version (db-process.js):

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/myproject';
var db = null;

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, database) {
    if(err){
        console.warn('Connection to MongoDB failed.');
    }else{
        db = database;
        console.log('Connected to MongoDB.');
    }
});   

process.on('message', function(msg) {
    switch(msg.name){
        case 'getRecord':   
            var collection = db.collection('SomeTable');
            collection.find({id: 'someId').toArray(function(err, docs) {
                if(!err) process.send{'name': 'getRecord', record: records[0]});
            });
            break;
        case 'saveRecord':
            // Code here...
            break;
    }
});
```

The challenge is that I want to be able to use the database module by passing callback functions. That will make it easier to use in all my other modules. But how can I put a variable from a event into a callback function? Is that even possible?

Below is shown my not-finished attempt in a simplified version (db-controller.js):

```
var childProcess = require('child_process');
var dbProcess = childProcess.fork('./db-process.js');

dbProcess.on('message', function(msg) {
    switch(msg.name){
        case 'getRecord':
            var record = msg.record;
            break;
        case 'saveRecord':
            // Handling here...
            break;
    }
});    

var controller = {};    

controller.getRecord = function(onQueryDone){
    dbProcess.send({name: 'getRecord'});
    // How to call the callback function with data when it is received? Basicly want the record variable from the switch.
    onQueryDone(record);
};

controller.saveRecord = function(record, onQueryDone){
    dbProcess.send({name: 'saveRecord'});
    // Handling...
};

module.exports = controller;
```

So i want to be able to use this module like this:

```
var dbController = require('./db-controller.js');

dbController.getRecord(function(record)){
    // Do something with record...
});
```

Any ideas of how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't pass callbacks between node instances (master and forked instances), but you can pass data.

What you would use in your case is a worker pool module, where the workers instances will handle all the db queries, and the master (the pool instance) will send the data to those workers and collect their results when they are done.

Here is one I did available on github [forked-worker-pool](https://github.com/asa-git/forked-worker-pool) but there are a few other alternatives on npm.

Answer (score 0):

The other alternative is to decouple your processes completely. I've used SQS on Amazon for this before, where I place data into a queue, and there is another server/process that listens for those items, wakes up and processes them. It's a pretty simply model. You could potentially use something like rabbitmq if you're not on AWS. That way your app server is never blocked, as it just dumps the data to the queue and continues.